# Finding input tags in the webpage using Webdriver with driver.findElements throwing exception. Why?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want to fetch the input tag items from the webpage using Selenium Webdriver.

Here is the html code :

```
<tr>
    <td class="listLabel" height="24 px">Username:</td>
    <td class="listData">
        <input type="text" tabindex="1" name="username" size="30">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="listLabel" height="24 px">Password:</td>
    <td class="listData">
        <input type="password" tabindex="2" name="password" size="30">
        <input type="submit" value=" Login " name="submit">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Till now what i have done is :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get(adminURL);

List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='listData']"));

System.out.println(listElements.size()); // gives the element size 2 which is valid.

for(WebElement el:listElements){
    el.findElement(By.xpath("//input[text()='username']")); //didnot find the element
}

System.out.println(" Title of the page is : "+driver.getTitle());
```

I am fetching the elements using xpath. But it didnot fetch the element with input type and text username.

It throws this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[text()='username']"}
Command duration or timeout: 113 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
System info: host: 'DS-7071BC8FD7AA', ip: '10.112.94.126', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Session ID: c1b5d8b8-43db-4157-8ab6-32286116d89a
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=32.0.3}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebElement.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:357)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.findElement(RemoteWebElement.java:167)
    at com.test.selenese.SeleneseTest.main(SeleneseTest.java:35)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[text()='username']"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.1', revision: '5163bce', time: '2014-09-10 16:27:58'
System info: host: 'DS-7071BC8FD7AA', ip: '10.112.94.126', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/rajan.v/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2185375942107103130webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9618:133)
    at <anonymous class>.FirefoxDriver.prototype.findChildElement(file:///C:/Users/rajan.v/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2185375942107103130webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9630:3)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/rajan.v/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2185375942107103130webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11612:16)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///C:/Users/rajan.v/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2185375942107103130webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11617:7)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///C:/Users/rajan.v/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2185375942107103130webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11559:5)
```

Support me to do it right way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it didn't work for me.. I tried it.

Comment: You're trying to find the `username` element that is located 'under' the `<td class=listData>`? Well that input doesn't have a text component. You'll have to find it using its `name` would be easiest. `el.findElement(By.name("username"));` the only text component belongs to the other element not to the one you used to build your initial list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

```java
el.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='username']"));
```

1. Add leading `.` to tell that the XPath is relative to current `el` element.
2. You're trying to filter element by attribute instead of inner text, so replace `text()` with `@attribute-name`

Comment: Beat me! I was commenting as you wrote this.

Comment: @MarkRowlands +1 for you. It works. But can you provide something like : get the list of all web elements with input tags and then find the selected attribute from the list of web elements to sendKeys() to them and then submit the form also. Because in the above code i want to do the same thing... I used findElements not findElement.