# Fetching all input textbox id's of a webpage in an array using java

Tags: java, html, selenium

How can I fetch all the id's of all the input text boxes in a particular webpage in an array.
For eg: I have a simple webpage which has around 5 input text boxes. I want to fetch all the id's of those input text boxes in a array of Strings.

Comment: Java or JavaScript ?

Comment: Code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
var res = [].map.call(elems, function(el) {
  return el.id;
});`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/11xjd2p6/

Comment: @Rayon consider selenium as the language

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254465/finding-input-tags-in-the-webpage-using-webdriver-with-driver-findelements-throw?rq=1